# how to create drag and drop mac installer?

Tags: cocoa, macos, installation, drag-and-drop, diskimage

I have made my java application's jar file and now want to create drag and drop installer for it.Also I want to know that how to create shortcut for Applications folder for the same purpose.
how can I do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to style a disk image? There's no such thing as a "drag and drop installer".

Comment: yes, I want to create a dmg file for installation.I have tried the Applications > utility > disk utility for this but what next? 

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Seth Willits' [DMG Canvas](http://www.araelium.com/dmgcanvas/) is a great and easy way to create customized DMGs (with things like an Applications folder shortcut, background image, etc).  Yes, you can do this all yourself with `hdiutil` and whatnot, but I much prefer using a GUI.

Answer (score 2):

You can Package your `.jar` into a `.app` (inside a dmg that has drag&drop) with `Javapackager` like this:

```
javapackager -deploy \
    -title "YourTitle" \
    -name "Name" \
    -appclass your.class.start \
    -native dmg \
    -outdir ~/Downloads \
    -outfile yourOutFileWithoutExtension \
    -srcdir "SourceDir"
```

you could use `-srcfiles Your.jar` if its only a single jar.

Answer (score 0):

Use either Disk Utility or the `hdiutil` command-line tool. It's easier to integrate `hdiutil` into an automatic build workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a small disk image containing your application and a symbolic link to the Applications folder. Use Disk Utility or hdiutil to create the image. You can just copy the application in, and create the symbolic link using Terminal:

```
cd /Volumes/DiskImageName
ln -s /Applications Applications
```